# Audio playback from arbitrary location on computer using AudioKit/Swift

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to build a native MacOS music player (a la musicbee, swinsian, itunes) that can play local files, but I'm stumbling at the first hurdle. The build succeeds but I get some error output and no audio plays. I can't really parse the error output, and the docs don't really provide examples of how to do this. Also, this is my first time using Swift/SwiftUI, so I might be missing something obvious. I am using XCode 14.3.1 and Swift 5 (`swift -v` shows 5.8, but in my compiler settings I just see "Swift 5". Not sure what's up with that).

My entire app is just one file:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AudioKit

class AudioPlayerManager {
  var player: AudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()

  func playAudioFile(at url: URL) {
    do {
      let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
      try player.load(file: file)
      player.play()
    } catch {
      print("Error loading audio file: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

@main
struct AlbumsApp: App {
  var player = AudioPlayerManager()
  
  init() {
    let externalFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/Downloads/test.mp3")
    player.playAudioFile(at: externalFileURL)
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

On running, I'd expect this to start playback of the file `test.mp3` but instead I get the following error:

```
2023-08-22 18:25:19.981575-0700 Albums[66917:7525085] [default]          ExtAudioFile.cpp:210   about to throw -54: open audio file
2023-08-22 18:25:19.982349-0700 Albums[66917:7525085] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioFile.mm:135:AVAudioFileImpl: (ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)): error -54
Error loading audio file: Error Domain=com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Code=-54 "(null)" UserInfo={failed call=ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &_extAudioFile)}
```

I can tell this is saying it's failed to load the audio file, but nothing about why that might be the case. I verified the path is correct, and have tried moving the file to my Desktop as one user here suggested in case it was a permissions issue, but no luck. Most of the other examples I see use `Bundle.main.url` to target something in their application bundle, but this is not what I want to do— I want users to be able to play arbitrary audio files using my app.

Comment: Consider that you are sandboxed. You cannot open an arbitrary file; you must let the user hand you the file.

Comment: you could try using `.fileImporter(...)` in your code to get the file url (from the user selection). Then proceed with that url.

Answer (score 0):

For the **AudioPlayer** to work an **AudioEngine()** must be running it seems. I tried modifying your code a bit and it seems to work without explicitly providing any kind of permission. Can you try it out and let me know if the error is still there.

```
class AudioPlayerManager {
  private let engine = AudioKit.AudioEngine()
  var player: AudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()

  func playAudioFile(at url: URL) {

    do {
      let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
      try player.load(file: file)
      engine.output = Mixer(player)
      try engine.start()
      player.play()
    } catch {
      print("Error loading audio file: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```